# How to style the number together with the item in an ordered list?

Tags: css

When I define an `.active` class for an ordered list item, the item number is not styled.

```css
li.active {
  background-color: #c5ecbe;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="i1" class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li id="i2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="i3">Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

How to style the number together with the item?

Comment: "*the item number is not styled*" - and which styles did you want to apply, all of them? Just some of them?

Comment: Just the `background-color` with `border-radius`. So the item is together with its number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list-style-position: inside`

```css
li.active {
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="i1" class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li id="i2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="i3">Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Simple, efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add some css and css counter

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(item) ".";
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

li.active {
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="i1" class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li id="i2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="i3">Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
li.active {
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="i1" class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li id="i2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="i3">Item 3</li>
</ol>
```